# BIND server serial number not updated

Tags: linux, bind, dns-zone

Please help with the following problem.

Serial number is not updated / incremented after I run "rndc reload"

Configuration:

OS: CentOS 7;

BIND: 9.11.4;

Port 53 is not blocked, listening, but my guess this is configuration problem not network;

Serial number example: "2021012809"

Execute: #rndc reload

```
     #server reload successful

     #rndc zonestatus myZone.com | grep serial

     #serial: 2020051510
```

All help appreciated.
Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have updated the zone file with new entries. To apply this change I need to increment serial number.

Comment: do you have bind slaves and is this the master?

Comment: Hi Jacob. I have master  >>>   [root@ddd]# rndc zonestatus mydomain.com
name: mydomain.com
type: master
files: mydomain.com.db
serial: 2020051510
nodes: 30
last loaded: Wed, 03 Jun 2020 18:06:17 GMT
secure: no
dynamic: no
reconfigurable via modzone: no

Comment: Dumb question: Are you _certain_ you're updating the correct zone file?  The log entries shown appear to be from a restart (or fresh start) of named - which tends to eliminate rndc from the picture.  (BTW, fix that "couldn't add command channel . . ." problem if you intend to use rndc going forward)

Comment: Brandon. It was not a DUMB question. You are right. Long story short, I reviewed one more time configuration and true. There is another zone file with the same name in different directory from where rndc takes update.  Need to organize things.  Thank you Brandon !

Comment: @birdflow no problem! And don't feel bad - anybody (self included) who has had to support bind on multiple distros and OSes (not to mention chroot jails) has done a similar thing.  Glad you got it worked out!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the serial number in the zone file yourself. BIND does not modify it. `rndc reload` simply tells BIND to reload zone information from files on the disk.

Comment: Hi Tero have updated it in the zone file itself. It simply not reflects after "rndc reload"